# Scattering approach for massless scalar Hawking radiation and Bogoliubov coefficients in Schwarzschild metric

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Reflection coefficient from the scattering approach in tortoise coordinates, looks exactly like relationship between modulus squared of Bogoliubov coefficients. However I'm not able to figure out a way to connect these two approaches.

Could someone please explain this or point me to an article, a paper or a book which explains this in detail?